# Wrapping tikz chains, multiline block diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts, block

I am trying to automate the generation of a multiline block diagram. So far with help ([old post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/692194/custom-data-structure-for-generating-tikz-flowchart)), I was able to generate a single sequence of block diagrams by using TikZ chains.
It is great for short processes, however, I would like to expand it to longer sequences of blocks and make it multiline. My idea to solve this would be to generate some fixed length (of 5 blocks for example) horizontal chains with vertical offset and later connect them via the chain connect option. Ideally, I would also try to flip the direction of the chain so that it goes like a zig-zag (or lawnmower pattern). I tried to split my chain into a few lines, but I got stuck while trying to create a list for iteration over rows. In short I would like to ask if there is some option or what would be the best way to achieve block diagram "wrapping" in TikZ.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin={1in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, arrows.meta, quotes}

\tikzset{block/.style={draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\createlist[1]{
  \int_step_function:nnN{0}{\int_eval:#1 - 1}{\int_eval:n}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\process}[1]{
    \newcounter{row_count}
    \foreach \blockstr/\outputstr/\descriptionstr [count=\n] in {#1}{
        \addtocounter{row_count}{1}
    }
    
    % five blocks per page should be ok
    % \{\pgfmathparse{int(ceil(\value{len} / 5))}\pgfmathresult}
    \def\nrows{{\pgfmathparse{int(ceil(\value{row_count} / 5))}\pgfmathresult}} 
    
    % \nrows
    % \def\mylist{{{0,...,\nrows}}}
    % \mylist
    % \def\mylist{\createlist{\nrows}}
    
    % \foreach \row [count=\i] in {0,...,\nrows}
    %     {
    %        \row
    %        }
        
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[start chain=diagram_chain going right, node distance=1mm and 1cm, 
                      every join/.style={thick, -Stealth}]
            \foreach \blockstr/\outputstr/\descriptionstr [count=\j] in {#1}{
                \node[on chain=diagram_chain, block, join=by "\outputstr"]{\blockstr};
            }
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{description}
    \foreach \blockstr/\outputstr/\descriptionstr [count=\k] in {#1}{
        \item [\blockstr] output: \outputstr \ \descriptionstr
    }
    
    \end{description}
}   

\begin{document}

\process{
    n0/$s(0)$/Long description of what n0 does,
    n1/$s(1)$/Long description of what n1 does,
    n2/$s(2)$/Long description of what n2 does,
    n3/$s(3)$/Long description of what n4 does,
    n4/$s(4)$/Long description of what n5 does,
    n5/$s(5)$/Long description of what n6 does,
    n6/$s(6)$/Long description of what n7 does
}



\end{document}
```

The result so far:
[image]

The target structure:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that only four columns will fit but this will depend heavily on the edge labels on the special joins.

All the smart things are happening in the `evaluate` part of the `\foreach` loop.

The key is that we can set the direction of the chain for each node on the chain separately: So for n1, n2, n3 we want it to be `going right`, for n4 we need `going below`, then n5, n6 and n7 are `going left` and `n8` is `going below` again.
The direction set with `start chain` is irrelevant (could just as well be empty).

The edge label will be placed via the `join` key from the `chains` library but we delay this for the next iteration because you specify the “output” label (i.e. the edge to the next node), though `join` describes the edge to a previous node. Thus, the `remember` key is used.

Based on the value of `process columns`, let's call it *n*, and each node *i* we determine

- the `\Direction` of the next node:

  - below if mod(*i*, *n*) is zero (i.e. it's the 0th, *n*th, 2*n*th, … node on the chain) ,
  - right if mod(*i*, 2*n*) is less then *n* (i.e. it is the 2*kn*+1st, 2*kn*+2nd, …, 2*kn* + 2*kn* + (*n*−1)th node on the chain)
  - left otherwise.
- whether we need a `\SpecialJoin` (and what kind) as well as
- the `\AutoDirection` so that the labels along the edges are always on top or to the outer side.

---

We could have TikZ or TeX measure things and maybe adjust the number of columns, at least for the next compilation run but I believe this to be a good start.

### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin={1in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, ext.paths.ortho}
\tikzset{
  every process diagram/.style={
    start chain=processes going right,
    every on chain/.append style={process node},
    every join/.append style={-Stealth, thick},
    node distance=3mm and 1cm,
    left join/.style ={to path={r-rl(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
    right join/.style={to path={r-lr(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
  },
  process node/.style={draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm},
  process columns/.initial=4}
\newcommand*\process[2][]{%
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every process diagram]
  \foreach[
    count=\i from 0,
    remember=\Output as \PrevOutput,
    evaluate={
      \NotVerticalLR=mod(\i,   \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/process columns} );
      \NotVerticalL =mod(\i,2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/process columns}));
      \Direction=ifthenelse(\NotVerticalLR, ifthenelse(\NotVerticalL<
          \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/process columns}, "right", "left"), "below");
      \SpecialJoin=ifthenelse(not(\NotVerticalLR),
        ifthenelse(\NotVerticalL, "left join", "right join"), "");
      \AutoDirection=ifthenelse(\NotVerticalL>
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/process columns}||\NotVerticalL==0,"right","left");
      }] \Text/\Output/\throwaway in {#2}
    \node[on chain=going \Direction,
          join=by {\SpecialJoin, auto=\AutoDirection, edge label=\PrevOutput}]{\Text};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
  \begin{description}
  \foreach\Text/\Output/\Item in{#2}{\item[\Text] output: \Output\par\Item}
  \end{description}}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\process{
    n0/$s(0)$/Long description of what n0 does,
    n1/$s(1)$/Long description of what n1 does,
    n2/$s(2)$/Long description of what n2 does,
    n3/$s(3)$/Long description of what n3 does,
    n4/$s(4)$/Long description of what n4 does,
    n5/$s(5)$/Long description of what n5 does,
    n6/$s(6)$/Long description of what n6 does,
    n7/$s(7)$/Long description of what n7 does,
    n8/$s(8)$/Long description of what n8 does,
    n9/$s(9)$/Long description of what n9 does,
    n10/$s(10)$/Long description of what n10 does,
    n11/$s(11)$/Long description of what n11 does,
    n12/$s(12)$/Long description of what n12 does
}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: If the nodes won't be uniform, i.e. they don't have the same width, it's going to be much more complex and measure intensive.

Comment: Thank you this is a really great solution and code!